# Adding ActionBar with the arrow "GoBack" to PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android

I have a PreferenceActivity. I'm looking for a way to add ActionBar with the arrow "GoBack" to it. All the examples I found so far have been, to my mind, overcomplicated because if I had a simple Activity I could add ActionBar to it with one line of java code and that would be it.

I wonder, isn't there a simple way to add ActionBar with the arrow "GoBack" to PreferenceActivity?

UPDATE:

Here's my Preference activity:

```
public class PreferenceActivity123 extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add this in your androidmanifest.xml file
     <activity
                android:name=".SecondActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".MainActivity" />
            </activity>
```

Comment: Write name of current activity instead of SecondActivity.

Comment: what's SecondActivity, is it MyPreferencesActivity?

Comment: second activity is your current activity name and mainActivity is your root activity name,

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [DisplayHomeasUpEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)) in your actionbar activity like

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);//Which will show back button
```

Define the parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml where the activity(PreferenceActivity) will be called once the back button in the action bar is pressed.

In your  definition on the Manifest, add the line:

```
 <activity
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.activities.PreferenceActivity"
  </activity>
```

or 
Just listen the optionItemSelected method

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**Edit** : 
In order to achieve same in Preference activity You need to make custom action bar style with back button in styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
  <style name="PrefTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/PrefActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <style name="PrefActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Call the style in manifest like :

```
<application android:theme="@style/PrefTheme">
```

Call the action bar in activity

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar() -- method not found.

Comment: If you are extending [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) then you are able to get that method. Which support sdk version you are using?

Comment: why would I extend it if I'm taking about PreferenceActivity? I've updated my question.

Comment: Are you able to call getActionBar method in your pref activity? I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);       

 Toolbar actionbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
        actionbar.setTitle("Settings");
        actionbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
        actionbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                YourActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });

        }
    }
```

and your activity_settings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              tools:context=".SettingsActivity"
              tools:menu="settings"
              tools:actionBarNavMode="standard"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:orientation="vertical"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where should I put that into?

Comment: R.id.actionbar -- not found.

Comment: I'll check that, thanks. But my code for SettingActivity is a bit different, I've added it to my question.

Comment: I updated answer. Just add setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings) to your activity after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); also create activity_settings.xml